# RSpec undefined method `to_sym'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My class is responsible for connection with the Jira company board which I want to test it.

`class`

```
module Jira
  class JiraConnection
    URL = 'https://company_name.atlassian.net/'.freeze

    def call
      JIRA::Client.new(options)
    end

    private

    def options
      {
        username: ENV['USERNAME'],
        password: ENV['PASSWORD'],
        site: URL,
        context_path: '',
        auth_type: :basic,
        use_ssl: true
      }
    end
  end
end
```

`JIRA::Client.new` comes from [jira-ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby). I want to test it

my specs:

```
RSpec.describe Jira::JiraConnection, type: :service do
  subject(:connect) { described_class.new }

  let(:options) do
    {
      username: username_secret,
      password: password_secret,
      site: 'https://company_name.atlassian.net/',
      context_path: '',
      auth_type: :basic,
      use_ssl: true
    }
  end

  let(:username_secret) { ENV.fetch('USERNAME') }
  let(:password_secret) { ENV.fetch('PASSWORD') }

  before do
    allow(JIRA::Client).to receive(:new).with(options)
  end

  it 'connect to Jira API' do
    expect(subject.call).to receive(JIRA::Client)
  end
end
```

With above specs I'm getting an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.call).to receive(JIRA::Client)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to_sym' for JIRA::Client:Class
   Did you mean?  to_s
```

Comment: `receive` expects a symbol as its first argument, representing the method to be called. You are passing a class `JIRA::Client`. What are you actually trying to do with this line?

Comment: I'm expecting to get connection with Jira board which represents of JIRA::Client class.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to test the *return value* of a method but using the `expect(...).to receive` API, which is for testing that *a method was called* (or, for stubbing a method).

If you want to check that the return value is an instance of `JIRA::Client`, you could do it like so:

```
expect(subject.call).to be_a(JIRA::Client)
```

Alternatively, using the more basic `eq` (equal) matcher:

```
expect(subject.call.class).to eq(JIRA::Client)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `expected: JIRA::Client got: NilClass` that's wired.

Comment: Not sure. Something's not working right with your code. Try using a debugger.

Comment: It will worked if inside before block I will return an object of instance_double

Comment: It's because you stub `new` in `before` hook.

Comment: Good catch phil

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want instead:

```rb
describe '#call' do
  it 'initializes Jira API client with proper connection options' do
    expect(JIRA::Client).to receive(:new).with(options).once
    connect.call
  end

  it 'returns Jira API client' do
    expect(connect.call).to be_a(JIRA::Client)
  end
end
```